# What is path data of android drawable mean

Tags: android

**I have a view:**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sel_to_arrow" />
```

**sel_to_arrow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">



    <path
        android:name="light_triangle"
        android:fillColor="#93186C"
        android:pathData="M 0,0 L 100,0 0,100 z" />


</vector>
```

What is the path data: `M 0,0 L 100,0 0,100 z` mean

which position is `top left`, which is `top right`, which is `bottom left`, which is `bottom right`

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/path-element.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**M or m (X,Y)**

moveto: Move the cursor to position, uppercase is absolute, lowercase is relative

**L or l (X,Y)**

lineto: Draws a line from the current position to the position specified by X,Y

**H or h (X)**

Horizontal lineto draws a horizontal line from the current cursor position to the position specified by X.

**V or v (Y)**

Vertical lineto draws a vertical line from the current cursor position to the position specified by Y.

**Z or z**

closepath: Draws a line from the current position of the cursor to the start position of the path.

**For all the above parameters uppercase means absolute position, lowercase means relative position.**

Answer (score 0):

The viewport height and width is given 100,So your bounds will be as follows

```
1.left - 0
2.right - 100
3.top - 0
4.bottom - 100
```

So you have to make the path based on these values same as in `Canvas` class's `drawPath()` method.

```
//draw rectangle
Path path=new Path();
path.moveTo(0,0);
path.lineTo(100,0);
path.lineTo(0,100);
path.lineTo(100,0);
path.close();

canvas.drawPath(path,mDrawPaint);
```

This will convert into

```
android:pathData="M 0,0 L 100,0 L 0,100 L 100,0 z"
```